# Can I modify and resell themes which are on WordPress official theme directory (100% GPL)?

Tags: gpl, commercial

According to [WordPress Licensing & the GPL](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/wordpress-licensing-the-gpl/), themes on the official WordPress theme directory should be **100% GPL**:

> If you wish to submit your creation to the free theme repository on
>   WordPress.org, it must be 100% GPL compliant, including CSS and image
>   files. Because the freedoms spelled out in the GPL are at the heart of
>   WordPress, we encourage developers to distribute their themes with a
>   100% GPL-compatible license.

Then as I know I can sell the themes after modifying. Am I correct?

Comment: You need to look at the license in a particular theme to make sure it is "100% GPL." Just because WordPress has a rule that all themes are 100% GPL, does not guarantee that this rule was always followed. For example, see [Problem About GPL Licence And WordPress Products](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14941/problem-about-gpl-licence-and-wordpress-products).

Comment: If theme is 100% GPL, can I sell it after modifing?

Comment: If the theme, artwork, text and everything in the theme are covered by the GPL, then the GPL allows you to redistribute derivative works and also charge a fee if you want. "100% GPL" is potentially confusing, though. It's possible that the source code is GPL, but the artwork is not (the specific artwork is not strictly required for the theme to function in WordPress). See the first linked question where this is discussed more fully.

Comment: As @Brandin says, "...then the GPL allows you to redistribute derivative works and also charge a fee if you want". However, the GPL would also require you to provide a free copy of that derivative source (or a link to it, etc). So it would be like offering users a choice: (a)pay me for it, or (b)take it for free. What do you think most users would choose? When people make money off of GPL software, they typically do it by selling support (or other after-market services not covered by the GPL).

Comment: @JohnForkosh I am not just reselling the theme. I will modified and resell... I mean adding more code....

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson The most common situation is when someone hires you and says "we want something like this, but modify this, that, and something else...". If everything is GPL it is fine to take it, modify it, and then sell the desired result to your client for a fee. Of course, your client must also receive that result under the same terms (GPL).

Comment: @JohnForkosh: You don't have to provide a free copy of the source to just anyone. What you must do under the GPL is to provide the sources to anyone who purchased the theme from you *and allow them to re-distribute the theme including sources*. The problematic part for most businesses is in the second part, because any competitor could buy a single copy from you and the re-sell it for a much lower price (including free).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can resell modified themes alright. And you will need to redistribute the modified source for these themes under the GPL. And someone can then redistribute these freely or take and resell them as they wish, as long everyone complies with the GPL, including modified source redistribution.

Comment: Agree: but you don't have to modify. And you are not responsible for others compliance.